# nodejs : how to make "sequelize then" to be synchronous?

Tags: nodes

```
var Tmp_Products = sequelize.define('tmp_products_list',{
    name : Sequelize.STRING,
    is_crawled   : Sequelize.BOOLEAN
},{
    freezeTableName : true
});

function get_tmp_products(){
    var ps = new Array();
    Tmp_Products.findAll({
        attributes : ['name'],
        limit : 10
    }).then(function(products){
        for(var p in products){
            console.log(products[p].name); //comment 1
            ps[p] = products[p].name
        }
    });
    console.log('ps',ps)  //comment 2
    return ps
}
```

In the place "comment 1"，it shows many products,but the place "comment 2", it shows a blank array.

I don't want it to be asynchronous here, I want the function finally return a product list, how should I do ?

Comment: why do you want to use asynchronous one ? That's not what nodejs is good at.

Comment: I want it to return product list to me , which is the final result , I don't want call then() everywhere in my code.

Comment: do you want to use callback ?

Comment: Yes , I like callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't change its async nature. Hope this helps

```
var Tmp_Products = sequelize.define('tmp_products_list',{
    name : Sequelize.STRING,
    is_crawled   : Sequelize.BOOLEAN
},{
    freezeTableName : true
});

function get_tmp_products(callback){
    var ps = new Array();
    Tmp_Products.findAll({
        attributes : ['name'],
        limit : 10
    }).then(function(products){
        //add something to check error
        for(var p in products){
            console.log(products[p].name); //comment 1
            ps[p] = products[p].name
        }
        console.log('ps',ps)  //comment 2
        callback(err, ps)
    });
}
```

Comment: what does callback do ? if callback like this : function callback(err,ps){return ps};  I think it will return me the blank array,too. If the callback tries giving the result to a global variable , then I don't think it's a good job.

Comment: really ? It's called after you get the full ps array.

Comment: Yes , but when I call get_tmp_products() , I want to get the result right now , or  block for the result . I don't want to check the result with a loop.

Comment: Now I know what you mean, I apology for my stupid. Thanks for your answer!